# Error allKeys on NSDictionary containing JSON objects

Tags: json, nsarray, nsdata

i try get json data from url but i get ERROR
this is my code;

```
self.NsData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://doctorapp.5plus.co.il/categories.php"]];
id jsonCategories=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:NsData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
self.categoriesArray=[jsonCategories allKeys];
NSLog(@"%@",[self.categoriesArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

### This is my error:

> [__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Answer (score 0):

```
self.data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://doctorapp.5plus.co.il/categories.php"]];
self.categoriesArray=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
self.categoriesNames=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i = 0; i < [self.categoriesArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary * dic = [self.categoriesArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * k;
        for (k in [dic allKeys]) {
            [self.categoriesNames addObject:[dic objectForKey:k]];
            NSLog(@"Temporary ports: %@", [dic objectForKey:k]);
        }
}
```